# How to flatten rows in Django by making call to server side

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I will try to explain at my best but comment if you find something missing.

I have a table and need to hide the rows based on the click on button. Below is my table image:
[image]

When I will click on `FLATTEN` button, it should hide that particular row by making call to server. I don't want to achieve this using Jquery or HTML Stuff.

HTML CODE:

```
{% for release in releases %}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="{{ release.apt_url }}">{{ release.version }}</a></td>
                    <td>v1</td>
                    <td>{{ release.release_status }}</td>
                    <td>{{ release.previous_version.version }}</td>
                    <td><a href="/releases/">
                        <button>Flatten</button>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

`Release is my model object`

Could anyone suggest me how can I achieve this ? `release.version` can be used to server as a primary key. But again, I don't want to delete the row just hide it when you can `Flatten` button. I can share more details but it should be sufficient.

```
My idea:
```

I am planning to send a request to my `urls.py` with `release.version` when button is clicked, and then in my `view.py`, I will send back a new `release model object` which don't have that particular version to my HTML side. I highly doubt this is a good approach to solve this particular issue. Could anyone suggest me some approaches?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this without reloading the entire page? If the button submits to a form view, you could toggle a model attribute on `Release` (say a new boolean field called `flat`), and then redirect back to the page view. And update your template to hide `release.flat == true`. This requires a page reload though.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I think it will work.

Comment: Thumbs up :) Issue resolved!

Comment: Sorry. I was away from my laptop. I could still provide an example if you like. But I'm glad you found a solution.

Comment: I implemented the solution you told you so thank you :).

Comment: If you could give an example on the answer section, I will accept it.